Next.js rerenders the entire layout.js on route change
I am using Next.js's App Router and the problem I am facing is navbar flickering every time I click on one of its links. This is because it rerenders each time.
My folder structure goes as follows:
src/
  app/
    components/navbar/navbar.jsx
    page1/page.jsx
    page2/page.jsx
    layout.js

In the layout.js
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
      <html lang="en" className="h-full">
          <body className="h-full">
            <NavbarComponent/>
            <main>{children}</main>
          </body>
      </html>
  );
}

I've seen multiple people having this issue but I couldn't find a single solution. Am I forced to switch to Page Router? Is it Next's bug or am I missing something? From what I understand anything at the same level as layout.js shares a layout and shared components should not be rerendered.
Someone suggested setting a fixed navbar height but that did not resolve the issue (not sure why it would anyways).
UPDATE: there is no flickering in Safari but there is in Chrome so tailwind might also be to blame here, however, I still think that rerendering is the root cause of this problem.

try with a head tag in your layout.js . I have similar layout just like you but mine works fine.In my layout.js i have head tag included.

I’m guessing this only happens when navigating from a sub route to the root route yes?
